# FreeNAS not correctly connecting to Active Directory - not seeing how to add Domain Accounts

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nfs, server-message-block, cifs, truenas

It looks fine from SSH:

```
[root@FREENAS1] ~# ping SERVER1
PING SERVER1.local.domain.com (192.168.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=0.265 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.365 ms
^C
--- SERVER1.local.domain.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.265/0.315/0.365/0.050 ms
[root@FREENAS1] ~# sqlite3 /data/freenas-v1.db "update directoryservice_activedirectory set ad_enable=1;"
[root@FREENAS1] ~# echo $?
0
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-kerberos start
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-nsswitch start
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-kinit start
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-kinit status
[root@FREENAS1] ~# echo $?
0
[root@FREENAS1] ~# klist
Credentials cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
        Principal: administrator@local.domain.com

  Issued                Expires               Principal
Jan  8 15:02:48 2017  Jan  9 01:02:48 2017  krbtgt/local.domain.com@local.domain.com
[root@FREENAS1] ~# python /usr/local/www/freenasUI/middleware/notifier.py start cifs
True
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-activedirectory start
Using short domain name -- INTERNAL
Joined 'FREENAS1' to dns domain 'local.domain.com'
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-activedirectory status
[root@FREENAS1] ~# echo $?
0
[root@FREENAS1] ~# python /usr/local/www/freenasUI/middleware/notifier.py restart cifs
True
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-pam start
[root@FREENAS1] ~# service ix-cache start &
[1] 75602
[root@FREENAS1] ~#
```

However, when I try and find the users/Windows Auth Options or CIFS under the sharing tab like I see in the guides, I am not seeing anything.

Am I missing something about how to add Domain users to SMB/NFS/CIFS shares?

Version:

```
FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE (FreeNAS.amd64) #0 r295946+47645f1(9.10.2-STABLE): Mon Dec 1                                             9 08:30:01 UTC 2016
```

EDIT:
I also turned on the Active Directory service that seems to also have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GUI go to Directory -> Active Directory. Join the Domain. This then builds a user cache. You can then set the owner for individual mountpoints to Domain Users/Groups under storage->permissions. Set the permission type to 'Windows'. You can now connect to FreeNAS with the Owner. Then you can set ACL through windows explorer.